# Kafka Connect logs are written in yesterday's file

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka-connect

Sometimes Kafka Connect logs are written in yesterday's file

```
$ tail connect.log
[2021-06-08 23:15:09,851] INFO Login successful for user my@KEYTAB.COM using keytab file /keytabs/my.keytab (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation)
[2021-06-08 23:15:09,855] INFO Login successful for user my@KEYTAB.COM using keytab file /keytabs/my.keytab (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation)
[2021-06-08 23:32:33,537] INFO Login successful for user my@KEYTAB.COM using keytab file /keytabs/my.keytab (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation)
[2021-06-08 23:42:44,281] INFO Login successful for user my@KEYTAB.COM using keytab file /keytabs/my.keytab (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation)
[2021-06-08 23:42:44,284] INFO Login successful for user my@KEYTAB.COM using keytab file /keytabs/my.keytab (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation)
$ tail connect.log.2021-06-07
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,303] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-1, groupId=connect-offset_test] Found no committed offset for partition offset_test-1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,303] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-4, groupId=connect-offset_test] Found no committed offset for partition offset_test-4 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,304] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-1, groupId=connect-offset_test] Resetting offset for partition offset_test-1 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,304] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-4, groupId=connect-offset_test] Resetting offset for partition offset_test-4 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,305] INFO Started recovery for topic partition offset_test-1 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,305] INFO Started recovery for topic partition offset_test-4 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,337] INFO Finished recovery for topic partition offset_test-1 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,337] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-1, groupId=connect-offset_test] Seeking to offset 489 for partition offset_test-1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,338] INFO Finished recovery for topic partition offset_test-4 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2021-06-08 23:42:47,338] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-offset_test-4, groupId=connect-offset_test] Seeking to offset 504 for partition offset_test-4 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer)
```

Like above, in `connect.log` there are only keytab login things.
And real application logs are in `connect.log.2021-06-07`!

To make matters worse, 2021-06-07's logs are nowhere.
But I'm sending those logs using ELK stack, so I know 2021-06-07's logs existed.

Does anyone know why this happens?

---

Here's my log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logFile

log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logFile.File=/kafka-connect/logs/connect.log
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out your log4j configuration,  there are different log appenders that effects logging, you might have a setting for one appender to roll to new day and another to keep writing to the same day, share your log4j configuration file if you need further assistance,  good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Added my log4j properties :)